# How to install mbstring in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: php, installation, php-7, mbstring, ubuntu-17.04

I have php version 7.0.22.
I tried doing

`sudo apt-get install mbstring` ,
`sudo apt-get install php-mbstring` ,
`sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring`

but every time it says
`Unable to locate package mbstring`

Please help.