# How to install php7.0-mbstring in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpunit

I'm trying to install `phpUnit` in my system. At first it asked to install `composer` then to install `mbstring`.Now I'm  I tried using all of the below,

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-fix-ubuntu-debian-apt-get-404-not-found-repository-errors
this. Still getting the same type of error.

> E: Unable to locate package php7.0-mbstring
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.0-mbstring'
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-mbstring'

This question is already asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733510/how-to-install-mbstring-in-ubuntu-17-04) but it doesn't have any answer.

**UPDATE:**
I tried [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo9Z4.png) [both](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxkL4.png) also.

[I have tried this link also.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491629/how-to-install-php-mbstring-extension-in-ubuntu)

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: if you are learner dont do it like install php mbstring .i recommend you install third party app called xampp ..https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: will you tried this one https://askubuntu.com/questions/491629/how-to-install-php-mbstring-extension-in-ubuntu

Comment: i have tried this too but still i'm grtting the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried searching for the package first? `apt search mbstring` it gives a list of packages that are available. If it is not available at all, you can not install it w/ a package manager. If none are listed, maybe grab the deb sury repros first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 17.04 is end-of-life as of January 13, 2018.  You can't grab php-mbstring because the release file for zesty-security repository no longer exists.

[Ubuntu Forums thread on this subject](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2382832)

Answer (score 0):

first, install mbstring with

```
apt-get install php-mbstring
```

or

```
apt-get install php7.2-mbstring
```

or

```
apt-get install php8.1-mbstring
```

then copy mbstring.ini manually to your php 7.0 like this :

```
cp /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/mbstring.ini /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mbstring.ini
```

enable mbstring mod with

```
phpenmod mbstring
```